# pinentry implementation with fingerprint sensor support

Tags: xcode, git, gpg

Currently, I am using `Pinentry Mac` from Xcode on my system to sign git commits. For this, I am having to input my passphrase each time I am waiting to sign a commit.

Seeing that my MacBook Pro has a fingerprint sensor I was wondering if there is a pinentry implementation can substitute password entry with a fingerprint check?

Comment: According to [this site](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/58498-gpgservices-pinentry-mac-keeps-asking-for-passphrase) you can store the passphrase in Keychain.  Have you tried that or are you looking for it to keep asking you but you want to use the fingerprint instead?

Comment: @fsb My password is pretty strong but if possible I'd like it to keep me asking for my fingerprint. It's quick enough not to bother me but adds additional security.

Comment: @Empty2k12 Perhaps this answer from SU is useful to you: https://superuser.com/a/1669784/82074